# What do you call a metallic bar projecting out of something that's used to support/carry an object?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for such thing? Think of a tank or vehicle with a metallic bar projecting to the side and that's used to carry some bag. Is there a name for something like that?

Here's an example:

> The ___ embedded into the truck was used to carry John's bag.

Comment: Did you mean to write "Think of a **truck** or vehicle..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the military, there are many names for things known only to the soldiers familiar with them.  I expect, if it exists, there is a specific term for something like this on a tank (although it's not clear why you would put a protruding metal bar on a tank, as it's a potential weak point in the armor), but I have no clue what it might be.

Colloquially you might call such a thing a "strut" or a "spar", depending on its purpose. However, both of these are normally load-bearing, functional items, and not just extraneous pieces sticking out from a vehicle.

So "bar" or "rod" might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, and I think it is **similar to** (maybe not exactly) what you want:
[image: A hanger holder]

It was on an online shopping website under the name:

> Car Truck *Seat Back* Bag Hanger Holder

You can ignore the "Seat Back" part as the *hanger holder* is not normally placed there in vehicles if they happened to have them, but above doors windows. And is popular to exist in public transportations such as buses.